# Google Ads not showing when my site is inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, adsense

I'm building a web application (a web site) which has a feature where you can embed it inside your own web site (using an iframe).
So, my app has Google Ads, and sometimes when the it is inside another site as embed (inside an iFrame) it doesn't show Ads, I mean, ads are being rendered, but sometimes that html from google is blank.

I'm concern about the Policy of GoogleAds and to not use iFrames to show ads, but I'm not using iframes to show them, my app is just inside another site as a feature.

My question is: can this be done?, or by that policy I won't be able to show ads on my embed feature?

**EDIT 1**
This is the content which Google is rendering (inside another iframe of another iframe):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:transparent" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  </body>
</html>
```

and also, I getting an error on the console:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "http://example.com". Protocols,
>   domains, and ports must match.

where "example.com" is some site that is using my feature

**EDIT 2**

So, I step at the Network tab of the console, and watch what was calling. Does a GET
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-XXXX.... With 200 OK always, but sometimes it returns just the blank HTML (posted above) and sometimes the actual html with an AD.

One more thing I didn't tell, I'm using the Asynch new Beta method, not the Synch, so I'm thinking of try the Synch and see what happens.

Comment: i bet the ad page has frame-busting headers.

Comment: Show the code webpage.

Comment: @dandavis what do you mean by "frame-busting headers"?, I'm not accessing the iframe, by all means, I'm just not doing anything with iframes on my app

Comment: Some web sites don't want to be embedded in others. They'll employ tactics to "bust out" of an iframe if they are loaded inside one. Basically site A embeds pages from site B in an IFRAME and tries to pass off B's content as a resource for A, B might use tactics to bust out resulting in the page redirecting to B's site and loading the page normally without A's wrapper. EDIT: I don't think that's what's happening here.

Comment: Regarding Edit 2, does Google show ads ALL the time? I would think occasionally the detected type of your site and any demographic information on the visitor might not match any worthwhile ad, right? I honestly don't know if Google ads always show *something* or not.

Comment: Yeah, so, I'm starting to hit Refresh and sometimes it just doesn't show ads, sometimes it does, so I'm starting to think that GET is not always retrieving ads. I'm now watching the HTML views, and render events, this is so weird. It's a good point that maybe just don't have ads for that client?, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try loading the page outside an IFRAME and run network capture on the traffic to/from Google. Explore the response headers - they might be using [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to prevent illicit click activity on ads. There's likely very little you can do about it aside from doing a server-side request and embedding the response HTML yourself. This will dramatically slow down your page loads and *might* violate your ad agreement.

EDIT:
After reading your follow-up testing, it sounds more like your site just doesn't meet the criteria of enough ad campaigns to serve ads with every request. I'd look at Google's FAQs or marketing information to find out how often ads are served or why you might not be getting ads on every request. Remember, the ads are for the benefit of the advertiser and they have good tools to make sure their ads are specifically targeted to the right audience to maximize their return. Your site just might not meet enough criteria to get many ads.

EDIT 2: A quick Google search turned up [this FAQ](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10036?hl=en) for why Ads might not be showing. They seem geared to why ads don't show at all, not intermittent appearance.

Comment: Wow!, so that means someone using the my embed feature, can disable ads for his site?

Comment: The X-Frame-Options is a server/host side option. If you're using Google Ads in an iframe, Google can supply X-Frame-Options that specifies how the content should be used. Likewise you can also specify your own X-Frame-Options should someone try to embed your pages. Likely Google's settings don't like double-embedding (child site embeds your site in an IFRAME which has Google Ads in another IFrame.)

Comment: I did what you told me and watch the network (I did it on my local without iframes, just calling the url that is used for the embed feature to an iframe), and it seems that the problem is not the actual iframe, cause it happens randomly without it :S

Comment: I was suggesting looking at the response headers to see what x-frame-options they might be using but if it's happening even without embedding, it's obviously not the issue then. My guess is your site just isn't getting served ads on every visit right now. You might not meet the criteria for the targeted advertising and only the "wide-open" campaigns are being shown. I'd check Google to see if there's a FAQ on when/how often ads will be served.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that there are a lot of things going on here, my web-site is primary a Javascript App, so it doesn't have much content like lot's of text in it. Another thing I saw is I should configure a backup_ad and also a google_alternate_ad_url so when google doesn't find ads to show I have a fallback to still show something. Thanks!